# Querying a database view in Postgres without a primary key using Spring JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have a view that I am trying to access from a postgres database.  The view does not contain a primary key, nor do the columns singly or compositely act as candidates for a primary key.  The many articles I have read propose using uuid, but since I cannot modify the view this is not an option.

Another thing I have read is mapping the view to a POJO class, but I am not quite sure I understand what that means.

For example, let's say for simplicity's sake I have a view that has the following information:

first_name
last_name
DOB

How would I map this view to a POJO class to now contain all the above information plus an ID which can serve as a primary key?  It's important to note, that I should not in any way modify the view in anyway. I assume since it's a view I wouldn't be able to.  If the view had an ID/PK I would just use the annotation @IMMUTABLE and have only getters.

Does this approach mean I am duplicating information in a new table with data from the view for the sole purpose of adding a primary key?

If these are the only two solutions available, can a list of steps be provided to implement the second solution?

Finally, is there a better way I can achieve querying a view without a primary key, than the two solutions mentioned above?

Comment: can you put what did you try so far to github ?

Comment: unfortunately, I cannot put this up on github, however, what I did which really wasn't the best case for this. I ended up creating a composite key since that was the only examples I could find online